# Matrix - String, Int, and Combined Operations

Tags: python, matlab

I want to be able to assign a string (a word) to an integer, and also an integer to a string, so that later on when i sort the integer or string, i can print the corresponding string or integer to that unit in matrix.
Example;

```
103 = QWE
13 = ASD
50 = ZXC
-1 = VBN
253 = RTY
```

and even multiple positions, like;

```
105 = QWE
103 = QWE
```

then,

```
matrix = [105,103,13,50,-1,253]
sort = [-1,13,50,103,105,253]

print sort_strings

# output: VBN ASD ZXC QWE QWE RTY
```

Just like in .cvs, when a column sorted other columns move according to keep row intact. And would like to do some additional functions on file, like classifying those strings after output so I can make some charts with color for visualization.

Thanks

Comment: Your tags are Python and Matlab. Which language are you using?

Comment: Python dictionaries might be of use here, since you can't really declare an integer as a variable and assign something to it.

Comment: Using Matlab you can create a vector of cells and assign each string to it's corresponding position. A{103} = 'QWE'; A{13} = '13', etc...  Although it may be inefficient if most of the positions are empty.

Comment: i am currently trying this on python, because it's easier to utilize python, if not promising, then will move on to matlab.

Comment: In python what you need is a dictionary https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries . You can get same functionality in Matlab with map conatainers http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python equivalent for HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588290/python-equivalent-for-hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by MATLAB.
I tried to do it using vectorization method. And it became the more and more unclear at each step but I spent a lot of time for it, so I show it:

```
a1 = ['qve';'rts';'abc';'abc';'def']
a2 = [3;5;10;7;8]
%//find unique strings:
mycell = unique(a1,'rows')

%//find numbers corresponded to each string. 
%//You can see there are 2 numbers correspond to string 'abc'
indexes = arrayfun(@(x) find(all(ismember(a1,mycell(x,:)),2)), 1:size(mycell,1), 'UniformOutput',0)

%//create some descriptive cell array:
mycell2 = arrayfun( @(x) a2(indexes{x}), 1:size(mycell,1),'UniformOutput',0)
mycell = cellstr(mycell)
mycell = [mycell mycell2'] %'

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%// now create test array (I use sort like you)
a3 = sort(cell2mat(mycell(:,2)))

%//last step: find each index of a3 in every cell of mycell and put corresponding string to res
res = mycell(arrayfun( @(y) find ( cellfun( @(x) any(ismember(x,y)), mycell(:,2))), a3),1)
```

`a1` and `a2` is input data. It creates manually. And `res` is a result you need:

```
res = 

'qve'
'rts'
'abc'
'def'
'abc'
```

P.S. It works! But it looks like some brainblow so I suggest to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is called "sorting arrays in parallel" or "sorting parallel arrays." You can use those terms to search for guides on how to do it. However, below is some code which shows one way to do it in MATLAB:

```
unsorted_keys = [95, 37, 56, 70, 6, 61, 58, 13, 57, 7, 68, 52, 98, 25, 12];

unsorted_strings = cell(size(unsorted_keys));

unsorted_strings = {'crumply', 'going', 'coyotes', 'aficionado', 'bob', 'timeless', 'last', 'bloke', 'brilliant', 'reptile', 'reptile', 'reptile', 'reptile', 'reptile', 'reptile'};

[sorted_keys, indicies] = sort(unsorted_keys);

% indicies = [5, 10, 15, 8, 14, 2, 12, 3, 9, 7  6, 11, 4, 1, 13]

% So, the 5th element of unsorted_keys became the 1st element of sorted_keys
% the 10th element of unsorted_keys became the 2nd element of sorted_keys
% the 15th element of unsorted_keys became the 3rd element of sorted_keys
% the 8th element of unsorted_keys became the 4th element of sorted_keys
% and so on.....
% sorted_keys == unsorted_keys(indicies)

sorted_strings = unsorted_strings(indicies);
```